# Search by key value tags

Tags: search, labels, tags

The UI is a web application. There is a set of thousands of objects. Each of them can optionally be labeled by 0-10 tags. Each tag is a key value pair - for example `color: red` or `taste: sour`.

The user should be able to search the objects based on 1-N tags. The interface should allow querying the objects based on:

1. tag existence - *Give me all objects featuring the tag key `color` - its value does not matter.*
2. tag value - *Give me all objects featuring the tag key's `color` value equal `red`.*
3. combination of above - *Give me all objects featuring the tag key `taste` **AND** featuring the tag's `color` value equal `red`*, etc.

---

Common web solutions like a tag-cloud or a simple auto-select box do not really fit - the tag-cloud selects only the key and auto-select produces only a key or a key value pair.

Having multiple auto-select boxes or even a "query" text input tend to be confusing.

Is there a clean UX solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a series of checkboxes and selectors.

Checking a checkbox would show a selector with a default value of "any", which means that anything tagged with the selected tag would be shown.

Then, the user could change the selector from "any" to more specific values (the selector could support multiple selections).

It could look like this, using progressive disclosure.

[image: three steps of a filter using progressive disclosure]

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks great for cases having low count of the available tags. Does it scale with the tag count? The real use case allows for new tags being defined by users. This means each object can *potentially* be labeled by up to 10 completely different user-defined tags. Therefore the total sum of different tags can be tens of thousands.

Comment: @Yuri - How many tag keys would there be? And would the user-defined tags have a tag key like "Custom" or another label that would keep them together?

Comment: Assuming the end users are use the tags in a sane way, the real-world tag key count would be 10-20. However, the users are still permitted to define new custom tag keys for *each* object (there are be objects having "special" properties). The current implementation features no way to differentiate between the Custom and Regular tag keys.